# How to read the output of "git verify-pack -v"

Tags: git, pack, git-verify-pack

I use `git verify-pack -v pack_file.pack` to get the list of all the objects contained in that pack.

The output is something like:

```
...
ca3c18fab3b277d9b7a70eae352175ca52ea1936 tree   67 75 21484
287edc22a3bba297bb2cc0fcac1a010ab87cc8d5 tree   99 107 21559
a469ac1d3fb2d5a8a2903875bd2981c3ee0dc1f6 tree   99 107 21666
360615f28f2c7409c97d46d6163c4d31a0e22dea blob   3086 1405 21773 1 85e0feee1d0cf66a2cdc469df1ea7d10a4b717d2
32cb35d3799ed230cf83b7d7778e8248dede4a2a blob   425 389 23178 1 889787d116be38832df44542b6a31e1b627d77e7
493d6d93cbea415628bed044df01bbbce918e0fc blob   30 61 23567 1 889787d116be38832df44542b6a31e1b627d77e7
775a650bd506dc6cda16bdfec01e874db9d288e0 blob   5253880 5245607 23628
ed139d6d50cc43f89c27392621f20d174d0bf051 blob   436 361 5269235 1 775a650bd506dc6cda16bdfec01e874db9d288e0
29ba8ed1be8238ba0c2de016e99e6b2f5f88c87a blob   47 75 5269596 1 581f246266ab3e409e8fb287dde9dad0cd255296
9846efeebfa8550498cb8fa0565f0d4f87416283 blob   644 386 5269671 1 581f246266ab3e409e8fb287dde9dad0cd255296
...
```

How can I read these lines? In particular if I take the following line:

```
360615f28f2c7409c97d46d6163c4d31a0e22dea blob   3086 1405 21773 1 85e0feee1d0cf66a2cdc469df1ea7d10a4b717d2
```

What are the number after "blob" (`3086 1405 21773 1`) and the hash at the end of the line (`85e0feee1d0cf66a2cdc469df1ea7d10a4b717d2`)?

Thank you.

Comment: Isn't the [documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-verify-pack) specific enough?

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I read that man page but in the rush for the search of an answer I missed that part of the documentation. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-verify-pack):

> When specifying the `-v` option the format used is:
>
> ```
> SHA-1 type size size-in-packfile offset-in-packfile
> ```
>
> for objects that are not deltified in the pack, and
>
> ```
> SHA-1 type size size-in-packfile offset-in-packfile depth base-SHA-1
> ```
>
> for objects that are deltified.